# How to print out a variable with all its (nested) type information?

Tags: types, rust

Given the current state of Rust and it's ecosystem (IDE support, documentation etc.) I find it quite hard to explore the language because I never now how to get a good overview of a type without looking at the source code.

I wonder if there's a `print` command that - given any variable as an input - prints out a nice representation of the type with all it's nested properties (if any).

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: What do you mean - explore the language? And why do you need the types at runtime to "explore" it? Most of the data structures are abstract, you're not supposed to know their internals. When you need to know about some structure and operations it provides, you usually look it up in [documentation](http://doc.rust-lang.org/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can only get output if all used types used in a struct have a `#[derive(Debug)]`.

E.g.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct X {
    a: Nested,
    b: i32,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Nested {
    c: u32,
    d: DeeplyNested,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct DeeplyNested {
    e: &'static str,
}

fn main() {
    let x = X {
        a: Nested {
            c: 8,
            d: DeeplyNested { e: "fun" },
        },
        b: -3,
    };
    println!("{:#?}", x);
}
```

Comment: Ah, got it. Do you have any other tips on how to explore the language? Racer? That seems to be only for Rust itself but not for external libraries such as `rust-http`right?

Comment: You can use `debug!("{}", exp)` to see how it executes. It won't run unless debug mode is on (and debug mode is off in tests). Other than that, just look at `rust` or `servo` code-bases for examples. See http://doc.rust-lang.org/rust.html#logging-system and http://doc.rust-lang.org/guide-testing.html